# spring-webflow jars not available

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, appfuse

I have wasted a 4 hours on finding a reason for not adding of webflow jars tp the reference library of my my modular maven project which is generated from appfuse.I want to add a webflow to this project. But when I do the registering as below, I get an error (I have still not run the project).

[image]

error is

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Class 'org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter' 
     not found
```

But I have included the webflow dependencies in my pom in my web module project. But when I go the the reference library I can not find the webflow jars as well. I think this is the reason for this, But I can not wind a way to get the jars in to the reference library.

The generated pom is very lengthy. I will add it if it is needed.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Is there a compatibility issue with the spring versions. I am currently using 4.0.0.RELEASE I have changed it to 4.0.2.RELEASE as well. But no luck. I can not find a meaningful solution for this. I really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse, right click the project and go to build path -> configure build path

From here, go to libraries and check that the Maven dependencies library is in there.

If its not click add library click maven managed dependencies, next, finish

Should add the libraries to the eclipse project